# Adding tags/category to exchange emails via python

Tags: python, email, exchange-server

I'm using python 3, and I want to add categories to certain emails.

I've identified that the categories appear under a 'keywords' section in the email. This way, I'm able to identify which emails have had a category set or not.

```
import imaplib
import email

M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host)
M.login(username, password)
M.select(folder)

# I'd love to be able to only search for emails without keywords here,
# but M.search(None, '(Keywords)') doesn't work
status, data = M.search(None, 'ALL')

for num in data[0].split():
    status, msg_data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    msg = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1], email.message.EmailMessage)

    # skip things which have categories already
    if msg.get('Keywords') is not None:
        continue

    # I want to categorise the message here, e.g. add a category 'approve'
```

The email server is exchange (I'm not sure what version they are using).

I know we can add flags onto the message like so

```
M.store(num, '+FLAGS', '//flagged')
```

But changing `'//flagged'` to something custom like `'\\approved'` gives a `imaplib.error: STORE command error: BAD [b'Command Argument Error. 11']`.

Also, I'm not sure the keywords are a flag thing?

**Edit:** I'm reading through [this](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3501.txt)(seems to be [supported by Exchange 2010, but I don't know if that's what's being used](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848256(v=exchg.141).aspx) and it seems keywords are flags, but don't start with \. Even so, using `(approved)` or `approved` doesn't work.

**Edit**: I tried to connect to the server via openssl. It shows

```
* FLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)] Permanent flags
```

which, since \* isn't an option, means that custom flags aren't accepted, hence why setting via +FLAGS wasn't working.

**Edit:** I am now using a workaround which is to add a new email with the keywords modified and then deleting the old one. It feels ugly but it works, I suppose...

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `exchangelib` for this:

```
from exchangelib import Account, Credentials, DELEGATE

account = Account(
    'me@example.com', 
    credentials=Credentials('myuser', 'topsecret'), 
    autodiscover=True, 
    access_type=DELEGATE
)
for email in account.inbox.all():
    email.categories = ['foo', 'bar']
    email.save()
```